# How to create a new subfolder to an asset with plugin

Tags: plugin-development, assets, subfolder

I have a plugin that uploads and associates files/assets to users and entries. I would like it to store these files under a user ID subfolder of the asset folder. I know how to do this within the controlpanel, working with assets there. But how would I create and register subfolders within my plugin? If I just create the folder with my php script, it doesnt show up in the assets folder until i do a "Update Asset Indexes".

The way my plugin works now, It creates an asset with the craft()->assets->insertFileByLocalPath, and then associates the fileId with my entry after its created/uploaded. Maybe this is not the right way to do it?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ve had the problem with `storeFolder()` that it doesn’t create a folder that is accessible via the control panel or the file system.

I find [createFolder()](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/AssetsService#createFolder-detail) much easier to use and it did what I expected:

```
$response = craft()->assets->createFolder($parentFolderId, $folderName);
$folderId = $response->getResponseData()['folderId'];
```

Comment: This is the right way of doing things. This not only also calls the storeFolder method, but also checks for naming conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, I found the answer in the source code.

```
$newFolder = new AssetFolderModel(
                array(
                    'parentId' => $currentFolderid,
                    'name' => $folderName,
                    'sourceId' => $currentFolderid,
                    'path' => trim($folderName, '/').'/'
                )
            );
            $folderId = craft()->assets->storeFolder($newFolder);
```

Basically you can specify a `parentId`, witch is the ID of the parent folder.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. Calling storeFolder just creates a folder in the database, not on the actual Asset source. @medoingthings has posted a much better way.